# Is there a function similar to TabbedTextOut() that can clip output like ExtTextOut()?

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a function similar to `TabbedTextOut()` that can output tab characters and clip the output like `ExtTextOut()` with the `ETO_CLIPPED` flag?

Comment: You can just install your own clipping rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply define a clip rectangle before calling `TabbedTextOut` to obtain the desired behaviour:

```
IntersectClipRect( hdc, 58, 40, 150, 80 );
TabbedTextOutW( hdc, 10, 50, tabbedStr, wcslen( tabbedStr ), tabCount, tabs, 0 );
```

**Full example (put in WM_PAINT handler):**

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps = { 0 };
HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

// Define a string with tabs and array of tab positions
const wchar_t* tabbedStr = L"Welcome\tto\tStack\tOverflow";
const int tabCount = 3;
int tabs[ tabCount ] = { 100, 200, 300 };

// Fill the whole client area with light green
RECT rc = { 0 }; GetClientRect( hwnd, &rc );
FillSolidRect( hdc, &rc, RGB( 200, 255, 200 ) );

// Output tabbed text without clipping for comparison
int oldBkMode = SetBkMode( hdc, TRANSPARENT );
TabbedTextOutW( hdc, 10, 20, tabbedStr, wcslen( tabbedStr ), tabCount, tabs, 0 );

// Set a clipping rectangle, fill it with white background and output
// clipped text
IntersectClipRect( hdc, 58, 40, 150, 80 );
FillSolidRect( hdc, &rc, RGB( 255, 255, 255 ) );
TabbedTextOutW( hdc, 10, 50, tabbedStr, wcslen( tabbedStr ), tabCount, tabs, 0 );

// Restore DC attributes
SetBkMode( hdc, oldBkMode );

EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
```

I hope this is valid C code as I'm usually a C++ guy. ;-)

`FillSolidRect` is there just for illustration purposes. It is defined like this:

```
void FillSolidRect( HDC hdc, const RECT* prc, COLORREF color )
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush( color );
    FillRect( hdc, prc, hbr );
    DeleteObject( hbr );
}
```

**Output:**

[image: TabbedTextOut with clipping]